# TextToSpeech to read single characters instead of words

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have some code which reads a string consisting in a mix of uppercase letters and numbers, reading one character at a time (as expected), but it fails to read `ZAR5004` one character at a time, instead it reads it as "five thousand and 4 African rand".

Is there a way to fix this, so that it reads one character at a time?

```
 tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
            tts.setPitch(.7f);
            tts.setSpeechRate(.6f);
        }
    });

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    protected void ttsGreater21(String readThis) {
    String utteranceId = this.hashCode() + "";
    activity.tts.speak(readThis, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you

Comment: Added as an answer, so that you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Comment: 1 5 3 0 0 X 5, the X is read "extension" and not "X". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a space or a dot (or try other separators) after each character. I.e.: `Z A R 5 0 0 4`

This will force the TTS Engine to treat the string as separate characters and speak them out individually.

Comment: Can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114281/highlight-text-as-it-reads-using-google-text-to-speech-in-android

Comment: @user2028 Please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870991/text-to-speech-show-read-words?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that won't help it highlights the whole text, I am using the same library for highlighting, In my case text is dynamic.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to add one word at a time, and read it before appending it to the TextView